# Why can't I remove this object's class / property

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I have a series of `divs` inside of which is another `div` which have several `imgs` appended to them.  I am trying to rotate through these images, (applying css transitions), and to do that I made a Javascript object which keeps track of the `div` and subdivs, and the images.  The way that I rotate through them is by making three arrays for the object. A `showing` `staging` and `holding` array.   When an image is shown it is put in the `showing` array, the one that was previously showing was put in the `staged` array and then later in the `holding array`.  When an image is added to the `showing` array of the object, I also set the class on it (this is how the transitions are done). For some reason I can add the class easily, but I just can't remove the class, which means eventually my animations stop.  I am adding the classes to the objects that are in my array, as opposed to using a `queryselector` but it should work, at least I think.

Using devTools I can see the classes being added but not removed. This is really bothering me.

Here is my **Javascript:**

```
var containerHolders = [];
    var imageHolders = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div.imageContent"));

    function Container(holder) {
        this.holder = holder;
        this.staging = [];
        this.holding = [];
        this.live = [];
        this.live[0] = holder.children;
    }

    imageHolders.forEach(function (holder) {
        var container = new Container(holder);
        containerHolders.push(container);
    });


    (function fill() {
        for (var i = 0, len = imageArray.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                var containerIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * containerHolders.length);
                containerHolders[containerIndex]['holder'].appendChild(this);
                containerHolders[containerIndex].holding.push(this);
            };
            img.src = imageArray[i];
        }
    })();



    function select() {
        var container = containerHolders[Math.floor(Math.random() * containerHolders.length)];
        if(container.holding.length) {
            var newer = container.holding[0];
            var old = container.live.splice(0, 1);
            old = old[0];
            old.className = 'staging';
            newer.className = 'live';
            container.live.push(newer);
            container.holding.push(old);
        } else {
            console.log('none');
        }
    }


    document.onclick = select;
```

If I had to guess I would say the problem is somehow related to the way I remove the classes from objects in the array as opposed to using some other method, but I am not sure. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You must remove newer from `container.holding`.

Comment: Furthermore: when you want to remove the first element of an array you better use `shift()`

Answer (score 0):

If JQuery is an option, you should use it. I realize that turning to a library for something that seems simple may not be ideal, but I've found that for any project I've worked on, once the project gets large enough, I usually end up using JQuery anyway. JQuery is very well suited for this kind of thing.

$(el).addClass('myClass');

$(el).removeClass('myClass);

Additionally, instead of using arrays to track your objects, if you were using JQuery, you can easily query for them using CSS selectors:

$('div.myClass').removeClass('myClass').addClass('myClass2');

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in `select()` function

```
function select() {
    var container = containerHolders[Math.floor(Math.random() * containerHolders.length)];
    if(container.holding.length) {
        var newer = container.holding[0];//here
        var old = container.live.splice(0, 1);
        old = old[0];
        old.className = 'staging';
        newer.className = 'live';
        container.live.push(newer);
        container.holding.push(old);
    } else {
        console.log('none');
    }
}
```

you will get the same image every time.

Comment: Saying that there's a problem on that line doesn't really answer the question, can you explain what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: var newer = container.holding[container.holding.length-1];